# How to save text with line breaks to Local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am currently facing a problem when saving text to local storage using javascript. When I save text from textarea to local storage and then display it again. The line breaks are shown as '/n' and are not actually being displayed as proper line breaks. How do I fix that?
This is how I am currently storing the text in the textarea:

```
localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notevalue))
```

and this is currently how I am displaying it.

```
document.getElementById("notes").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("notes");
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with local storage? Setting `.innerHTML` won't necessarily show line breaks in the resulting UI (Unless you use specific elements/CSS rules)

Comment: HTML ignores line breaks and only treats `<br>` as line break

Comment: how may i display line breaks then?

Comment: @Donut Replace with `<br>` or wrap in `<pre>` tag

Comment: how can I do that? What I am currently doing is getting the value of the textarea and using replace() but I am not sure on how to pull it off.  let change = notevalue.replace();
    document.getElementById("notes").value = change;

Comment: `.replace("\n", '<br/>')`